# How to start a for loop from the end of a vector, and at the value 0 do something

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have to start looping a vector from its end to zero. When I meet the value 0 I need to replace it with the sum of the **three** previews values. The exception will be for the first zero met, I need just to sum the previous two values.

e.g.

```
v = [0, 5, 5, 0, 6, 6, 0, 7, 7 ]
```

Expected result:

```
v = [36, 5, 5, 26, 6, 6, 14, 7, 7 ]
```

Code

```
for i in range(len(v), 0):       
    if v == 0 :
        v[i] = v[i+1] + v[i+2] + v[i+3]
```

The code is not working. Where am I wrong?

Comment: `if v == 0 :` is wrong. `v[i] = v[i+1] + v[i+2] + v[i+3]` is wrong for `i >= len(v) - 3`. `sum(v[i+1:i+3])` could help here.

Comment: `range(len(v), -1, -1)`

Comment: Try v[::-1] that way the list is sorted backwards

Comment: @ArthurHarduim That's not useful here because he's assigning to list elements and needs the indexes to go in reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid index errors with `sum(v[i+1:i+4])`. You have to compare each element (`if v[i] == 0`) not the whole list.

```
v = [0, 5, 5, 0, 6, 6, 0, 7, 7 ]

for i in range(len(v) - 1, -1, -1):       
    if v[i] == 0 :
        v[i] = sum(v[i+1:i+4])
print(v)
```

Comment: Anyway, I debugging your code but I am still unsure about your solution. It works, but I cannot understand why. I cannot understand the sum(v[i+1:i+4]) especially the +4. Should not be +3 at most?

Comment: @chrisis  Because slicing (`[i+1:i+4]`) is inclusive on the left side and exclusive on the right side. These are up to 3 elements, not 4. `v[i:i]` is an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.accumulate` on `reversed` list to get the sums and then switch to the sum in positions of where 0s exist in the original -

```
from itertools import accumulate

acc = list(accumulate(reversed(v)))  #list of cumsums
sums = [j if i==0 else i for i,j in zip(reversed(v), acc)]  #switch to cumsum where 0 exists in list
out = list(reversed(sums))  #reverse it back
print(out)
```

```
[36, 5, 5, 26, 6, 6, 14, 7, 7]
```

Comment: thanks again but it is too complected for me :) thanks again for your help

Comment: glad to help. do try to see if you understand this approach as well! would help in the long run if you are learning :). Itertools is a powerful set of methods and list comprehensions are the pythonic way of writing loops!

Answer (score 0):

```
v = [0, 5, 5, 0, 6, 6, 0, 7, 7 ]

for i in range(len(v)-4,-1,-1):
    if v[i] == 0 :
        v[i] = v[i+1] + v[i+2] + v[i+3]

print(v)
```

this gives the exactly what you want. but the zeros that are in last 3 won't get modified because there is no other 3 for adding. and the result is

```
[22, 5, 5, 12, 6, 6, 0, 7, 7]
```

Comment: thanks for contributing @FLAW! please do check that the output is not the same as expected by OP. Do update your answer thanks!

Comment: my man what was the flag for ? I got a solution, yea there is a better solution @Thomas Sablik . mines was lacking with adding last 3. but I don't think that deserves a flag. I tried the problem, got a solution. and you flag bc my solution wasn't perfect ha ?

Comment: I didnt flag or downvote my friend. feel free to check my profile. I only politely commented, I dont downvote specially for new users :)

Comment: ok then sorry. I was learning python for a few months and opened this profile just today. but I didn't get, what was wrong? I ran this code and it gave me exactly this list. I'm aware this wasn't what asker wanted and I said this lacks with last 3. is OP some kind of jargon that I don't know or something else here ?

Comment: I think the issue is your output not your approach `[22, 5, 5, 12, 6, 6, 0, 7, 7]`... OP is expecting `v = [36, 5, 5, 26, 6, 6, 14, 7, 7 ]`. Some people downvote for that but dont get discouraged. we all face it now and then

Comment: thanks man! felt lucky for come across to such a polite man in my first answer. and a Data Scientist with 8+ years of experience in AI & Machine Learning... just admired, man :)